# Historical NCAA football poll rankings by week?

Tags: data-request, sports, historical

Is there a source for historical weekly poll rankings for NCAA football? Ideally something like the AP poll, but any of them would do, I would just like to look at yearly rankings in the beginning of seasons matched against final season performance.

Answer (score 1):

I came across wikipedia links (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_NCAA_Division_I_FBS_football_rankings) that starting in 1996 appear to sort of have what I'm looking for.  I'll see if I can put together a scraper to try and assemble what I had in mind.